# hide facebook authorization dialog iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

I have a program that authorize on facebook with cookies. So the modal dialog with facebook authorizing every time displaying. I want to hide it from user. Any help please..

Answer (score 0):

When your login was successful you could do something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

then when your application starts up, do something similar to this:

```
    if ( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBAccessToken"] != nil ) {
        _facebook.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBAccessToken"];
        _facebook.expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDate"];
    }
```

What this is doing is, that it saves the "cookie" of the facebook authentication and reuses it when the application is restarted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I login successful to facebook using cookies. I need to hide this modal view from user..

Comment: You can only hide this dialog if you persist the cookies. If you persist the cookies, then the dialog won't appear again until the cookie expires.

Comment: I just wanted to say that when I restarting my application this dialog appears again.. I have cookie in my DataBase..

Comment: Are you sure, you actually _restore_ the cookie ?